# Create German currency format

Tags: android, numbers, currency

I'm going to create a German currency format in Android, I just can't get the thousand, million, separator work. This is what I did so far:

```
String bill_subtotal = String.format("%.2f", bill_amount);
txtSubtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubtotal);
txtSubtotal.setText(String.valueOf(bill_subtotal).replace(',', '.'));
```

Those above only make values like this: 60000.50 into 60000,50
I want to make it 60.000,50

Is there a way to make it like that?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I will, but at the moment im away from pc, i will update asap, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is ,

```
public static String formatGermanCurrency(double number) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return nf.format(number);
}
```